# Nadaraya - Watson Envelope Strategy

Tags: pine-script, finance, trading, tradingview-api, technical-indicator

Completely new to pine script. Been trying to make a strategy using Nadaraya-Watson Envelope but its shows no output on the Strategy Tester. Here's the Code.

I just want to make a simple strategy based on a boolean (envelopeCondition) which is set to true or false depending on whether the close value is outside the envelope, but the boolean value does not seem to update.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Envelope", overlay=true, initial_capital =1000, default_qty_value =100, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)

bool envelopeCondition = false

length = input.float(500,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
h      = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult   = input.float(3.) 
src    = input.source(close,'Source')

up_col = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col')
dn_col = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col')
disclaimer = input(false, 'Hide Disclaimer')

n = bar_index
var k = 2
var upper = array.new_line(0) 
var lower = array.new_line(0) 

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to length/k-1
        array.push(upper,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower,line.new(na,na,na,na))

line up = na
line dn = na

cross_up = 0.`your text`
cross_dn = 0.`your text`
if barstate.islast
    y = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e = 0.
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        
        for j = 0 to length-1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        
        y2 = sum/sumw
        sum_e += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        array.push(y,y2)

    mae = sum_e/length*mult
    
    for i = 1 to length-1
        y2 = array.get(y,i)
        y1 = array.get(y,i-1)
        
        up := array.get(upper,i/k)
        dn := array.get(lower,i/k)
        
        if src[i] > y1 + mae and src[i+1] < y1 + mae
            envelopeCondition := false
            

        if src[i] < y1 - mae and src[i+1] > y1 - mae
            envelopeCondition := true


if envelopeCondition
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)
else 
    strategy.close("Long")
    
plot(na)
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely caused due to the fact that `envelopeCondition` is never `true`.

The reason of that is that while you think you are checking the condition `if src[i] < y1 - mae and src[i+1] > y1 - mae` for the amount of times stated in the `for` loop, you are actually getting the result of only one run, and that is since each run you are changing the value of `envelopeCondition`.

If you are changing it on each run of the `for` loop, at the end of the for loop you will only get the last value of `envelopeCondition`, which is `if src[length-1] < y1 - mae and src[length] > y1 - mae`. If this one condition (which its value is set basically only once on this script) is not `true` than you will never enter a trade.

Comment: Aha I see, so should I be executing a trade on each iteration instead of after the whole for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but usually using a `for` loop to check entry decision can cause more harm than good if not used properly. Keep in mind that the script runs on each bar close, so you might don't want to check the entry condition only on the last bar (and than iterate previous bars using a `for` loop) since that even if it will return `true`, the trade will occur only on the last bar. I would rethink the whole thing, keeping in mind that the script runs on each bar close